# Setup and teardown functions executed once for all nosetests tests

Tags: python, nosetests

How to execute setup and teardown functions once for all nosetests tests?

```
def common_setup():
    #time consuming code
    pass

def common_teardown():
    #tidy up
    pass

def test_1():
    pass

def test_2():
    pass

#desired behavior
common_setup()
test_1()
test_2()
common_teardown()
```

Note that there exists a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427734/how-can-i-define-one-setup-function-for-all-nosetests-tests?s=1%7C3.6396) with an answer that is not working with python 2.7.9-1, python-unittest2 0.5.1-1 and python-nose 1.3.6-1 after replacing the dots with `pass` and adding the line `import unittest`.
Unfortunately my reputation is too low to comment on that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have a module level setup function. According to [nose documentation](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/writing_tests.html):

> Test modules offer module-level setup and teardown; define the method
>   setup, ***setup_module***, setUp or setUpModule for setup, teardown,
>   ***teardown_module***, or tearDownModule for teardown.

So, more specifically, for your case:

```
def setup_module():
    print "common_setup"

def teardown_module():
    print "common_teardown"

def test_1():
    print "test_1"

def test_2():
    print "test_2"
```

Running test gives you:

```
$ nosetests common_setup_test.py -s -v
common_setup
common_setup_test.test_1 ... test_1
ok
common_setup_test.test_2 ... test_2
ok
common_teardown

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

It does not matter which name you choose, so both `setup` and `setup_module` would work the same, but `setup_module` has more clarity to it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Sorry, my description was not clear enough. The setup() and teardown() functions should be called only once for all tests. I edited my question to clarify this issue.

Comment: Changed the answer to reflect the comment.