# How to define a setup method only called once during testing with nosetest?

Tags: python, nose

I am running a couple of `nosetests` with test cases in different modules (files) each containing different tests.

I want to define a function/method that is only called once during the execution with `nosetest`.

I looked at the [documentation](http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/doc_tests/test_doctest_fixtures/doctest_fixtures.html) (and e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30750621/setup-and-teardown-functions-executed-once-for-all-nosetests-tests)) and see there are methods like `setup_module` etc. -  but where and how to use them? Put them into my `__init__.py`? Something else?

I tried to use the following:

```
class TestSuite(basicsuite.BasicSuite):
    def setup_module(self):
        print("MODULE")

    ...
```

but this printout is never done when I run the test with `nosetest`. I also do not derive from `unittest.TestCase` (which will result in errors).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When looking at a package level, you can define a function named `setup` in the `__init__.py` of that package. Calling the tests in this package, the `setup` function in the `__init__.py` is called once.

Example setup

```
- package
    - __init__.py
    - test1.py
    - test2.py
```

See [documentation](http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/writing_tests.html#fixtures) section 'Test packages'.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
from nose import with_setup

def my_setup_function():
    print ("my_setup_function")

def my_teardown_function():
    print ("my_teardown_function")

@with_setup(my_setup_function, my_teardown_function)
def test_my_cool_test():
    assert my_function() == 'expected_result'
```

Holp it helps ^^